# Socket.io reconnection with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I'm trying to add socket.io as a new angular service.

The server can disconnect the client that didn't get authed.

The client can connect the server again later.

The problem I found that it's not possible to handle previous listener events for the new connection. Is it necessary to add new listeners to the socket connection? How to reuse previous listener events?

```
angular.module('services')
.factory('socket', function($rootScope, ENV) {
            var socket = io.connect(ENV.chatServer,{'forceNew': true });

            return {
              reconnect: function (id, accesstoken) {
                console.log('socket.reconnect()');
                //socket.io.reconnect();
                socket = io.connect(ENV.chatServer,{'forceNew': true });
                socket.on('connect', function(){
                  socket.emit('authentication', {uid: id, accessToken: accesstoken });
                });
              },
              disconnect: function () {
                socket.io.disconnect();
              },
              on: function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                  var args = arguments;
                  $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                  });
                });
              },
              emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                  var args = arguments;
                  $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                      callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                  });
                });
              }
            };
          });
```

Comment: Can you confirm that [this](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) is the socket.io component you're trying to integrate?

Comment: I just added socket.io client library (/socket.io/socket.io.js) to index.html, I will try that library, thx

Comment: https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io/issues/86 solved my problem